# Replace for-loop with apply()?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am trying to optimise my R code and I have started replacing loops that have been implemented “quick and dirty” with functions and so on. I have now arrived at a situation where I believe the apply-function would be handy.  I cannot wrap my head around it though.

```
a <- c(10,20,15,43,76,41,25,46)
c <- c(2,5,8,3,6,1,5,6)                               
myframe <- data.frame(a,c)
newframe <-vector(length=3)
constant <- data.frame(a,c,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,c)

a.function <- function(frame){
  newframe <- frame*22
  return(newframe)}

result <-  matrix(nrow=nrow(myframe),ncol=3)

for(i in 1:nrow(myframe)){
  newframe <- a.function(myframe[i,])
  newframe[ncol(myframe)+1] = i 
  newframe[ncol(myframe)+2] = constant[i,9]
  #more columns added
  newframe <- rbind(result,newframe)
}
```

I have tried to reduce the loop as far as possible and I hope it can still be understood.
Going through the rows of a dataframe should be the prime example for the use of a for function. Still I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: I've added a working example.

Comment: What is your intended result?

Comment: You are `rbind`-ing functions. This code makes no sense.

Comment: Can you post some data from `my.frame` so we have a better idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: We can't help you optimize code that doesn't run.  You've got syntax errors and undefined objects.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've now added a working example. I hope this helps...

Comment: `apply` functions are not faster than for-loops. Distrust anyone who tells you otherwise. Exert your effort to make the code inside the loop correct and efficient.

Comment: This looks wrong: `newframe[ncol(myframe)+1] = i `. Perhaps wanted: `newframe[[length(myframe)+1]] = i` , although since  there are no comments it's not entirely clear that you wanted a "constant"-`i` column on the right side of that new dataframe.

Comment: well it's just an example. a series of constants from different global vars is added...

Comment: an `apply` function will return a result to you, not modify an existing data.frame (i.e. add variables to it, like you have done).  The only part of you `for` loop that looks like you may want to `apply` is the first line, which could become `apply(myframe, 2, a.function)`

Comment: apparently I had the wrong understanding `apply`. Is there any way I can optimise this? The real myframe has over 100,000 rows with 500...

Comment: @user3347232 You need to explain what you are trying to do.  If you just want to add columns you don't need to loop by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code overwrites itself. Instead of saving each run through of the loop. You're rewriting newframe every loop through with data from myframe. Basically the only thing your loop does is run the last value of i which is nrow(myframe)

```
newframe <- a.function(myframe[nrow(myframe),])
newframe[ncol(myframe)+1] = nrow(myframe)
newframe <- rbind(newframe,newframe)
```

and

```
result <-  matrix(nrow=nrow(myframe),ncol=3)
```

is never even used.

Comment: Sorry the example code is wrong then. it should be `rbind(result,newframe)`. I have changed the example...